# integral calculus with $e^{x^2}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

How can I show that

$\int_{0}^{1}x^{2017}e^{x^2}dx=\frac{e}{2018}-\frac{2}{2018}\int_{0}^{1}x^{2019}e^{x^2}dx$

Comment: integration by parts should help

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integrating by parts,

$$\int {e^{x^2}x^n}\ dx=e^{x^2}\int x^n\ dx-\int\left(\dfrac{d(e^{x^2})}{dx}\int x^n\ dx\right)dx$$

$$\implies\int_0^1{e^{x^2}x^n}\ dx=\dfrac{e^{x^2}x^{n+1}}{n+1}\vert_0^1-\dfrac2{n+1}\int_0^1e^{x^2}x^{n+2}\ dx$$

Can you recognize $n$ here?

Comment: I got it. Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Now it looks like a stupid question...

Answer (score 0):

$$\dfrac{d(x^ne^{x^2})}{dx}=nx^{n-1}e^{x^2}+2x^{n+1}e^{x^2}$$

Integrating both sides between $0$ and $1$,

$$ 1^ne^{1^2}-0^ne^{0^2} =n\int_0^1x^{n-1}e^{x^2}\ dx+2\int_0^1x^{n+1}e^{x^2}\ dx$$

Can you recognize $n$ here?

Comment: Thanks for your help

Comment: @point, Welcome! Btw, do you see any mistake here?

Comment: what is Btw? I try it on my papers here first

Comment: @point,  Btw = By The Way

Answer (score 0):

$$\int_0^1\! x^{2017}\mathrm e^{x^2}\,\mathrm dx=\int_0^1 \!x^{2016}\,\mathrm e^{x^2}x\,\mathrm dx,$$
and setting $t=x^2,\;\mathrm dt= 2x\,\mathrm dx$, you obtain
$$\frac12\int_0^1\!t^{508}\mathrm e^{t}\,\mathrm dt.$$
Now denoting $I_n=\displaystyle\int_0^1\! t^n\,\mathrm e^t\,\mathrm dt$ and integrating by parts, we get the recurrence relation:
$$I_n=\mathrm e-nI_{n-1} $$